# How to click on the button with text 'Sure!' using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a problem when opening

https://pribot.org/polisis/?company_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhotmail.com&status=policyAbsentRedirect

with selenium on firefox. I am using python.

I want to run this code to click "Sure!" button but it does work, simply no errors.

help!

My code is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn theme--dark primary'][@type='button']").click()
```

please note when I execute this code the pop up layer that contains "SURE" button disappeared but the SURE button action is not applied. As if I am clicking ESC.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://pribot.org/polisis/?company_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhotmail.com&status=policyAbsentRedirect")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]').click()
```

Use above snippet it's working fine for me.
You need to wait for 3-5secs explicitly.
Hope it helps!!
If not, please let us know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [url](https://pribot.org/polisis/?company_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhotmail.com&status=policyAbsentRedirect) with in your question, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://pribot.org/polisis/?company_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhotmail.com&status=policyAbsentRedirect")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dialog dialog--active dialog--persistent']//button[@class='btn theme--dark primary']/div[@class='btn__content']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: pribot]

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to click the element that contains the text, 'Sure!'. The only way to do that is using an XPath that specifies the desired text. You can use the XPath below.

```
//div[.='Sure!']
```

Since that popup doesn't appear initially on page load, you will want to add a wait, e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Sure!']"))).click()
```